# Need letter document generator for PHP with HTML input

Tags: html, php

I need a framework / plugin for PHP which input is accept any HTML tag include `<table>` and `<img>` for creating letter like Ms. Word's "Mail Merge"
Better if it can do page setting.

I've tried Jasper Report, but I am unable to add those html tag to template.

**EDIT**
I have data from database to be generated for some kind bussiness letter. All inputs are written in HTML tag format including create table and add image.

Also, the output can be shown in HTML format and can be PDF format.

I've tried to play around with Jasper. Seems in good shape but I can't put tag `<table>` and `<img>`. But the content sometimes need table or image.
Using pure HTML document cannot make good quality letter, where the placing seems out of position.

Comment: Can you clarify you question?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.